# Config location for global / command line Node.js tool

Tags: node.js

I am creating a command line tool for Node.js and would like to give my users the ability to create configuration for it, so that they don't have to specify a lot of arguments at the command line. I am not familiar with the preferred methodology here. Is there a preferred way in Node.js-land to place config files for globally installed modules? There is no need to install the module locally anywhere, just globally, as it's a command line app.

Answer (score 1):

You can place configuration files for global cli commands in the user's home directory. For example, the `npm` command used a config file present in `~/.npmrc` by default.